# Mocha test successfully connecting to my database but not saving instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

**src/user.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name : String
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

**test/test_helper.js**

```
// DO SOME INITIAL SETUP FOR TEST

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useMongoClient : true });

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connection
    .once('open', ()=> console.log('Good to go'))
    .on('error',(error)=> {
        console.warn('Warning',error);
    });
```

**test/create_test.js**

```
const assert = require('assert');
const User = require('../src/user');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

describe('Creating records', () => {
    it('saves a user', () => {
        const joe = new User({ name : 'Joe' });
        joe.save();
    });
});
```

When I am trying to save the instance in the create_test.js , its not saving it in the database. But when I save an instance in the file test_helper.js , it is working .  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's because mongoose opens connection *after* that the test is running. You need to use *before* hook to guarantee that connection is opened.

```
before(done => {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useMongoClient : true });
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

  mongoose.connection
    .once('open', () => done())
    .on('error', err => console.err('Db connection error', err);
  });
});
```